# Invasive Green Shoots and Tubers

Tags: roots

I have these really annoying green shoots coming up all over my backyard and they all connect to bigger roots below the ground. Also, whenever I dig to put in a new plant I’m finding these ovular-shaped tuber things. I’d like to know if the two are related, which tree they’re coming from and what, if anything, I can do about them. The tree circled in red is the one I suspect is the problem but I’ve included other possible culprits. Please let me know if you need any other information. Thanks in advance!

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hAi9.jpg

Comment: I fixed your image link, but I think you should upload all the individual images. SE posts are supposed to contain all the relevant information and not require users to follow links. This ensures posts will continue to be useful (links can and do get broken), is more secure, and also saves users time. Thanks! 

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! How exactly do I go about adding the other images? I’d like my post to be as easy to access and assess as possible.

Comment: You're welcome! After clicking on the [edit] link under your post you should see an image icon (looks like two mountain peaks with a moon). Click somewhere in your text (make sure this isn't inside another link) and then click on the icon to add another picture. If you get an error message, make sure that you are trying to add an image (e.g. a '.jpg' file). Does that help?